# MOD function in excel

Tags: excel, modular-arithmetic

This is an observation more than anything.

I have two values 0.02 (or 2%) in cell A1 and 0.12 (or 12%) in cell B1.

Now when I do the equation "=MOD(B1* 100, A1* 100)" it returns 2, which makes no sense.

To correct for this I do "=MOD(INT(B1* 100),A1* 100)" and it properly returns 0.

Anyone know why the first one returns a 2?

Comment: Funny, it returns 0 for me.

Comment: How are the values in `A1` and `B1` produced? Are they the result of formula(s)?

Comment: @BigBen One is a straight input, the other is a result from a formula [namely: "=(cell above) + 0.01"]

Comment: Unable to reproduce a result of 2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/uglJO.png. There's some rounding error, but definitely not 2.